# Java Web Service throws a NullPointException after I made a MySQL query on Implementation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, nullpointerexception, request

I have been working in web services with java. I built the wsd before the Java (Top-Down). The problem is that I made some classes to request data from a MySql database. In the method of SOAPImpl I create an Object of the class **Usuario**, but when I test the service with SOAP UI, it shows an NullPointerException.

This is the code

DataBase.java

```
package negocio;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DataBase
{
    private String conexion;
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    Connection conexionBase;
    Statement estado;

    DataBase()
    {
        this.conexion = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/agua";
        this.user = "1234";
        this.pass = "1234";

        this.preparaDB();
    }

    public void preparaDB()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try
        {
            this.conexionBase = DriverManager.getConnection (conexion, user, pass);

            estado = conexionBase.createStatement();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Statement getEstado()
    {
        return estado;
    }
}
```

Usuario.java

```
package negocio;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Usuario extends DataBase{

    private String clave;
    private String nombre;
    private String paterno;
    private String materno;

    public Usuario()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Usuario(String clave)
    {
        super();
        cargaUsuarioClave(clave);
    }

    public void cargaUsuarioClave(String clave)
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE numeroCliente = '" + clave + "'";

        try
        {
            ResultSet resultado = this.getEstado().executeQuery(query);

            while(resultado.next())
            {
                this.clave = resultado.getString("numeroCliente");
                this.nombre = resultado.getString("nombre");
                this.paterno = resultado.getString("paterno");
            }

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }

    public String getClave()
    {
        return this.clave;
    }

    public String getNombre()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getPaterno()
    {
        return this.paterno;
    }

    public String getMaterno()
    {
        return this.materno;
    }

}
```

AguaSaneamientoSOAPImpl.java

```
 /**
 * AguaSaneamientoSOAPImpl.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

package org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import negocio.Usuario;

public class AguaSaneamientoSOAPImpl implements org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.AguaSaneamiento_PortType{

    public org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.ConsultarServicioPropiedadResponse consultarServicioPropiedad(org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.ConsultarServicioPropiedadRequest parameters) throws java.rmi.RemoteException 
    {
        return null;
    }

    public org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.ConsultaServicioUsuarioResponse consultaServicioUsuario(org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.ConsultaServicioUsuarioRequest parameters) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return null;
    }

    public org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.InfoPagosUsuarioResponse infoPagosUsuario(org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.InfoPagosUsuarioRequest parameters) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return null;
    }

    public org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.InfoUsuarioResponse infoUsuario(org.example.www.AguaSaneamiento.InfoUsuarioRequest parameters) throws java.rmi.RemoteException 
    {
        Usuario us = new Usuario("2");

        InfoUsuario [] infoUser = new InfoUsuario[1];

        infoUser[0] = new InfoUsuario("Enrique", "14 Sur", "345", "6");

        InfoUsuarioResponse infoRes = new InfoUsuarioResponse(infoUser);

        return infoRes;
    }

}
```

I tested the Usuario class and it works, but, when I call the cargaUsuarioClave inside the infoUsuario method, the webservice returns a JavaNullPointException. This is the response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">SERVER</ns1:hostname>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I don't know what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem, It wasn't the source code, the problem was the connector file; I needed to copy tath file into the lib folder of my project.